# How do you pass a button click as a function argument?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Coin Flip</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
    <h3>Let's flip a coin! Choose heads or tails:</h3>

    <button onclick="flip()" id="choice">Heads</button>
    <button onclick="flip()" id="choice">Tails</button>

    <h3 id="guess"></h3>
    <h3 id="result"></h3>
    <h3 id="confirm"></h3>
  </body>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
function flip(choice) {
    // Declares random number variable
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1;

    // Conditional random win/loss
    if(randomNumber==1){
        document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "You guessed " + choice + "...";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The coin flips and comes up Tails!";
        document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Good Guess!";
        
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "You guessed " + choice + "...";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The coin flips and comes up Heads!";
        document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Good Guess!";
    }
}
```

I am making a simple coin flipping game using HTML and JS. I am having trouble printing the choice the user makes (heads or tails). Is there a way to pass what button they clicked as the text "heads" or as the text" tails"? Check JS for text that will print out.

Comment: You can pass parameters through the onclick attribute. `flip('heads')` or `flip('tails')`. Alternatively, within the `flip` method, you can use the keyword `this` to access the HTML element that called the function. From there, you can get the [inner text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText), or use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Do not duplicate ids either assign `class='choice'` to both of them or `id='heads'` and `id='tails'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass heads or tails as the parameter in the function call:

```html
<button onclick="flip('Heads')" id="choiceHeads">Heads</button>
<button onclick="flip('Tails')" id="choiceTails">Tails</button>
```

```js
function flip(choice) {
    // Declares random number variable
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1;

    // Conditional random win/loss
    if(randomNumber==1){
        document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "You guessed " + choice + "...";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The coin flips and comes up Tails!";
        document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Good Guess!";
        
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "You guessed " + choice + "...";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The coin flips and comes up Heads!";
        document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Good Guess!";
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Coin Flip</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
    <h3>Let's flip a coin! Choose heads or tails:</h3>

    <button onclick="flip('Heads')" id="choiceHeads">Heads</button>
    <button onclick="flip('Tails')" id="choiceTails">Tails</button>

    <h3 id="guess"></h3>
    <h3 id="result"></h3>
    <h3 id="confirm"></h3>
  </body>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! So much simpler than what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Do not duplicate ids. For details see comments in the exanmple.

```js
// Bind click event to each <button>
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => btn.onclick = flip);

// Define event handler -- pass Event Object
function flip(e) {
  // Reference the <button> user clicked
  const picked = e.target;
  // Get the value of picked and convert string to number with '+'
  let side = +picked.value;
  // Get random integer in the range of 1 to 2
  let outcome = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1;
  // Reference <output>
  const out = document.querySelector('output');
  // If the value of picked equals the random number...
  if (side === outcome) {
    // Assign winning string with picked id interpolated
    out.value = `${picked.id}! You win!`;
  } else {
    // Otherwise assign losing string to <output>
    out.value = `${picked.id}! You lose!`;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Coin Flip</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Coin Flip</h1>
    <p>Let's flip a coin! Choose heads or tails:</p>

    <button id='Heads' value='1'>Heads</button>
    <button id='Tails' value='2'>Tails</button>

    <p><output></output></p>

  </body>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```